# How to capture DOM nodes created with Javascript and save in MySQL using JQuery AJAX & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simply Javascript client script that consist of an an HTML button and when clicked it creates new DOM nodes, each with their own ID per an incrementing counter. For each click the dom node name ( div1, div2, div3, etc) gets pushed to an array that holds one div at a time.

When the user clicks **#orange-button** I want each DOM node to be stored to mysql via PHP for later recall.

Below is what I have thus far & I commented what I do not understand.

**Javascript**

```
var temp = [];

$('#orange-button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add.php',
            data: temp,             // Not sure if this is right !
            success: function(){
                $('#success').html();
            }
        });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
$gimme = $_POST[temp];   // Not sure how to do this line

$sql="INSERT INTO synths (domID)
VALUES ('{$gimme}')";
```

Comment: 1) Data must be a key-value paired object. 2) Values should be strings, not DOM elements. You would therefore want something like `data: {html:myEl.innerHTML}`, then in PHP: `$_POST['html']`

Comment: What do you mean by "an array that holds one div at a time"? If it only holds one div, why does it have to be an array?

Comment: I should just use a variable but I did that for testing/learning  purposes as a precursor to using the array the correct way per php mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "temp" variable will hold an array of IDs

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'add.php',
    data: {mydata: temp},             // Pass the data as json
    success: function(){
        $('#success').html();
    }
});

$gimme = $_POST['mydata'];   // I called the POST variable "mydata"

foreach($gimme as $value){
    $sql="INSERT INTO synths domID = $value";
    //then execute it
}
```

Don't insert them all in one query. Instead do it in a loop.

But really should use PDO instead: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers